# How to hide the default android webview progress bar?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, webview, android-progressbar

i work on an app that displays a page through a webview. I have implemented my own progress bar and it works fine. However i cannot get rid of the default android progress bar that keeps showing up (the three gray dots). The round progress indicator is mine the dots are the default.

[The problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UGcfp.png)

My XML:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <androidx.swiperefreshlayout.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    android:id="@+id/swipeLayout">


    <ViewFlipper
        android:id="@+id/simpleViewFlipper"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <WebView
            android:id="@+id/splashWebview"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            />

        <WebView
            android:id="@+id/webview"
            style="@android:style/Widget.Material.Light.WebView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            />

        <ProgressBar
            android:id="@+id/progressBar"
            style="?android:attr/progressBarStyle"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:visibility="gone"
            android:indeterminateTint="#000000"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
            />
    </ViewFlipper>

   </androidx.swiperefreshlayout.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>
```

I only have this problem with the webview with id=webview.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In WebView there is no progress by default while loading the web page, the three-dot progress that you are viewing must be from the website which you are loading